# What is the difference between the Microchip XC8 and C18 compilers?

Tags: mplab-c18, xc8

I want further understand the difference between XC8 & C18 compiler.

I know that XC8 is the latest compiler for all 8-bit microchip controllers. e.g. PIC16F, PIC18F. And C18 is the compiler for their PIC18 products. For C18, PIC18 series include both PIC18F and PIC18C, is it?

I see XC8 is the further edition comparing to C18. Is it means XC8 can also compile all / part of the code compiled by C18 previously. If not, what should be.

BTW, currently (days) I am searching for sample/tutorial code about PIC18F2455/2550/4550 USB interface. If you have any pointers they would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference is that the XC8 compiler "does not support the PIC18 extended instruction set; code is always compiled for the standard PIC18 instruction set". Another is the MPLAB XC8 compiler "does not currently support preprocessor macros with variable argument lists". Quotes are from the migration manual. Microchip is phasing out the C18 (the only compiler I've used to generate code for their 18F products) but there seems to be a fair number of complaints about XC8.

The Microchip PICDEM FS USB Demo Board was originally based on the 18F4550 (now 18F45K50). The schematic for it is in the documentation. There is also a lot of sample code for it in the 'Microchip Solutions Library'. All that plus more is downloadable for free on their site.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is XC8

1. does not support recursion
2. does not support dynamic function pointers